# Is SwiftUI build on top of UIKit?

Tags: swiftui, uikit

i can't explain why extension on UIKit's UIPickerView affects on SwiftUI's picker.

and does that mean that knowing basics of uikit is very useful for learning swiftui?

does it even make sense to learn swiftUI if it's basically UIkit library(if I am right)

```
extension UIPickerView {
    open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: 200)
 }
}



GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Picker(selection: self.$daySelection, label: Text("")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< self.days.count) { index in
                        Text("\(self.days[index]) d").tag(index)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                Picker(selection: self.$daySelection, label: Text("")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< self.days.count) { index in
                        Text("\(self.days[index]) d").tag(index)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                Picker(selection: self.$daySelection, label: Text("")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< self.days.count) { index in
                        Text("\(self.days[index]) d").tag(index)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.wheel)
```

[image: MultiPicker]

This extension solves problem of overlapping gesture areas of pickers in ios 15.

Answer (score 2):

1. Is SwiftUI built on top of UIKit?

No... and yes, sometimes.

There are controls in SwiftUI that do reach into UIKit to use those. Although, not all of them.

And as Vacawama rightly pointed out… if running on MacOS then AppKit also.

The thing about SwiftUI is to not worry too much about the underlying technology. It may be that Apple chooses to significantly rewrite the foundation of it. Perhaps taking a previously used UIKit component and writing it natively in SwiftUI. But the SwiftUI code shouldn’t change.

2. Is SwiftUI a UIKit library?

No, absolutely not. They are fundamentally different ways of thinking about and creating UI.

3. Does it make sense to learn SwiftUI?

Yes, it makes sense to learn SwiftUI AND UIKit. Also, Combine and CoreGraphics and GameKit... Do you want to be an iOS developer or a SwiftUI developer?

4. Random bit of badly indented code...

I'm not sure what this is doing in your question.

Comment: please check update code in the question

Comment: @AlisherBaigazin it still isn't really relevant to your question. If that's how that code is working then that's how it works. Then probably the Picker in question does reach into the UIKit control (for now). Is there an issue with the code that you need help with?

Comment: Additional note for #1.  SwiftUI uses UIKit on iOS, but on other platforms (such as macOS) it uses that platform's native UI kit (AppKit).

Comment: My question is why it works like that, like why I need to extend Uikit's UIPickerView to fix my SwiftUI picker. no need help with code just discussion. like I'm tryin understand how it works under the hood, and thanks for the answer by the way

Comment: @vacawama Thanks, can you send any resources about that?

Comment: I don't have any documentation to present.  While working with SwiftUI, I've noticed errors in the console that reveal what's going on under the hood.  I've seen Autolayout errors (ah ha, so they are using Auto layout) which mention UIKit and AppKit components.  In reality, we're not supposed to think about SwiftUI in this way.  Apple may only be using these underlying components as a short cut to get SwiftUI out the door.  They are free to rewrite them natively if they choose.  We shouldn't care.

Comment: The nice thing about SwiftUI is that it is cross platform.  You can run the same code on different platforms, and what SwiftUI uses to present your interface can/will differ depending on the platform that is using it.

Comment: Ah yes, it hadn’t crossed my mind about the cross platform functionality of it. Thanks 